# tabulator - how to extract just the data and save as json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

is there a way to save all data inside a tabulator table into a variable in jquery/javascript? 
I noticed that they have a

```
table.downloadToTab("json");
```

method which is cool but instead of opening up into new browser, I just want to save to a variable.

I know I can write my own javascript / jquery code to loop through the rows and cells but it looks like they don't use a traditional table with `<tr>` and `<td>` but everything is a  with specific class names.

For example this is all the HTML that's created for just one row of data in a tabulator table:

```
<div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-odd" role="row" style="padding-left: 30px;">
   <div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-row-handle tabulator-frozen tabulator-frozen-left" role="gridcell" title="" style="width: 30px; position: absolute; left: 0px; height: 29px;">
      <div class="tabulator-row-handle-box">
         <div class="tabulator-row-handle-bar"></div>
         <div class="tabulator-row-handle-bar"></div>
         <div class="tabulator-row-handle-bar"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="id" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 29px;">
      2134561
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="first_name" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 29px;">
      jane
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="last_name" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 29px;">
      doe
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="company" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 29px;">
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="email" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 29px;">
      janedoe@testing.ca
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="title" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 29px;">
      &nbsp;
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="registered" title="" style="width: 150px; height: 29px;">
      &nbsp;
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="speak" aria-checked="false" title="" style="width: 167px; text-align: center; height: 29px;">
      <svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="14" width="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
         <path fill="#CE1515" d="M22.245,4.015c0.313,0.313,0.313,0.826,0,1.139l-6.276,6.27c-0.313,0.312-0.313,0.826,0,1.14l6.273,6.272  c0.313,0.313,0.313,0.826,0,1.14l-2.285,2.277c-0.314,0.312-0.828,0.312-1.142,0l-6.271-6.271c-0.313-0.313-0.828-0.313-1.141,0  l-6.276,6.267c-0.313,0.313-0.828,0.313-1.141,0l-2.282-2.28c-0.313-0.313-0.313-0.826,0-1.14l6.278-6.269  c0.313-0.312,0.313-0.826,0-1.14L1.709,5.147c-0.314-0.313-0.314-0.827,0-1.14l2.284-2.278C4.308,1.417,4.821,1.417,5.135,1.73  L11.405,8c0.314,0.314,0.828,0.314,1.141,0.001l6.276-6.267c0.312-0.312,0.826-0.312,1.141,0L22.245,4.015z"></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="paid" aria-checked="false" title="" style="width: 167px; text-align: center; height: 29px;">
      <svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="14" width="14" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xml:space="preserve">
         <path fill="#CE1515" d="M22.245,4.015c0.313,0.313,0.313,0.826,0,1.139l-6.276,6.27c-0.313,0.312-0.313,0.826,0,1.14l6.273,6.272  c0.313,0.313,0.313,0.826,0,1.14l-2.285,2.277c-0.314,0.312-0.828,0.312-1.142,0l-6.271-6.271c-0.313-0.313-0.828-0.313-1.141,0  l-6.276,6.267c-0.313,0.313-0.828,0.313-1.141,0l-2.282-2.28c-0.313-0.313-0.313-0.826,0-1.14l6.278-6.269  c0.313-0.312,0.313-0.826,0-1.14L1.709,5.147c-0.314-0.313-0.314-0.827,0-1.14l2.284-2.278C4.308,1.417,4.821,1.417,5.135,1.73  L11.405,8c0.314,0.314,0.828,0.314,1.141,0.001l6.276-6.267c0.312-0.312,0.826-0.312,1.141,0L22.245,4.015z"></path>
      </svg>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="example" title="" style="width: 167px; height: 29px;">
      <a href="mailto://email" target="_blank">janedoe@testing.ca</a>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></div>
      <div class="tabulator-col-resize-handle prev"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

A lot of html!
but I can write the code... i just want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: You can get the data as 2D array with `table.getData()`

Comment: Any way to get data on the table if it's been filtered? getData() seems to get the original data... but I'd like to grab only what the user is currently looking at.

Comment: Sure, you can pass `true` as argument in order to only get the filtered data.

Comment: tabulator has json exporter too I think (apart from csv, xlsx, pdf ones) and you can specify which columns you want available for download and what is the downloadTitle for each one)

Comment: ...see http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/download#advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Tabulator's [`getData()`](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/update#retrieve-data) method:

```
var array = table.getData();
```

This will return all the table's data as a 2D array. If you want to only get the data that is currently filtered (visible to the user), then pass `true` as argument:

```
var array = table.getData(true);
```

And you can use the native [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function to produce JSON in case you need to transfer/persist this data somehow:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Comment: perfect!  exactly what I was looking for.